# Why does it prompt the user twice in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an annoying bug where the user gets asked twice about their age, even if the user inputs a valid age.  I will paste the entire code, but the problem seems to be in the while loop. I know it loops 5 times but if the user gets it right the first time, it proceeds to ask them again.

```
i = 1
for i in range(5):
    i +1
    try:
        age = ''
        while age < 1 or age > 130:
            age = int(raw_input('Enter in your age... '))
            both = str(age)
            if age == -1:
                print 'Exiting'
                time.sleep(.5)
                print 'x----'
                time.sleep(.5)
                print 'xx---'
                time.sleep(.5)
                print 'xxx--'
                time.sleep(.5)
                print 'xxxx-'
                time.sleep(.5)
                print 'xxxxx'
                print 'Exited'
                LOL.exit()
            if age < 1 or age > 130:
                time.sleep(1)
                print 'Enter in your actual age'
            else:
                break
    except ValueError or NameError:
        print 'Please use your actual age, not %s!' %both
        time.sleep(1)
if i > 3:
    print 'YOU\'RE LOCKED OUT!!'
    LOL.exit()
```

Comment: please include only relevant code.

Comment: This is too much code to go through to find the problem.

Comment: the while loop works fine for me. Weird thing to init age to an empty string...

Comment: Its asking age five times due to your for loop `for i in range(5)`.

Comment: you have it wrapped in a loop to be done 5 times

Comment: Sorry, I had someone complain that I didn't show enough a little bit ago so I thought I would fix that.  Sorry for the mess. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I know that it loops five times(I should have put that in the post) but the problem is when the user gets it right the first time, I will continue to ask them again.  Thanks!

Comment: it continues because you tell it to do it five times `for i in range(5)`

Comment: @user3709398 so what is the problem?

Comment: When you nest loops, the *entire* inner loop happens for *each* iteration of the outer loop, in general. Your inner loop asks for an age. Even if "the user gets it right the first time", that only represents a successful completion of the *inner* loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the

```
for i in range(5):
```

As far as I can tell, it's not necessary.

You also have a few other issues with your approach, in my opinion. See if this gives you a head start.

**UPDATE** a couple issues with my first suggestion. This is better.

```
import time

age, i = '', 0
while age < 1 or age > 130:
    i += 1
    if i > 3:
        print 'YOUR LOCKED OUT!!'
        LOL.exit()
    if age == -1:
        print 'Exiting'
        for s in range(1,6):
            time.sleep(.5)
            print ('x' * s) + ('-' * (5 - s))
        print 'Exited'
        LOL.exit()
    if i > 1:
        time.sleep(1)
        print 'Enter in your actual age'
    age = int(raw_input('Enter in your age... '))
```

Comment: I appreciate this so much! I always like to see how I can improve my code.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3709398 no worries. Just think about what you are doing ... you want to loop until the user gets is right, then use while ( and then if you want to put a max tries on it, use that `if` statement. Just be careful of the order - it matters as you can see if you try my first version and my latest. :)

Comment: @user3709398 and pay attention any time you see the same thing ( or close ) over and over again. My `print ('x' * s) + ('-' * (5 - s))` is not the most elegant way to do that, but I wanted you to think through how you could do it in a loop.